# async await vs Result from higher level call?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have this simple repository method:

```
public async Task<Blog> GetById(int id)
{
    return await _dbContext.Blogs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

I read some answers about async await, but I still don't understand how to call this GetById method properly:

```
public async Task DoSomething1()
{
    var blog = await _blogRepository.GetById(1);
    Console.WriteLine(blog.Title);
}
```

or

```
public void DoSomething2()
{
    var blog = _blogRepository.GetById(1).Result;
    Console.WriteLine(blog.Title);
}
```

Properly means: without blocking the thread like described in this post:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Personally I think, that correct way is DoSomething2 in this situation. 
Because thread blocking happens when FirstOrDefaultAsync is running, so this is reason why I use async and await in GetById method, so is it really need to use one more async await in higher methods like in DoSomething1? can I use Result in this situation like in DoSomething2?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of choices?

(I use .NET 4.5)

Comment: If you call DoSomthing2() from main thread of Windows Forms or WPF application, it will cause a deadlock. The rule thumb is "do not block on async operations". By trying to get the .Result value, you are blocking the calling thread.

Comment: _(I use .NET 4.5)_ - but is it WPF, WinForms, MVC?  The question is not complete without the toplevel.

Comment: This is console application (not WPF or UWP). I think that thread is blocking when FirstOrDefaultAsync is calling to database. So I use this call with async await. Is it really need to use one more async await in higher methods, when this is console or mvc application?

Comment: In a Console blocking the main thread isn't a real problem. It won't deadlock. You could use an `async Task Main()` , C# > 7.1, but that is purely cosmetic. To really learn about async, write a WinForms app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding first implementation(DoSomething1) You can read here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await

> An await expression does not block the thread on which it is executing. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the async method as a continuation on the awaited task. Control then returns to the caller of the async method. When the task completes, it invokes its continuation, and execution of the async method resumes where it left off.

Regarding second (DoSomething2)
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_Result

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.
>
> Once the result of an operation is available, it is stored and is returned immediately on subsequent calls to the Result property. Note that, if an exception occurred during the operation of the task, or if the task has been cancelled, the Result property does not return a value.

To prove it, You can check thread id's before executing and after. For example

```
var threadId1 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
var blogPost = await DoSomething1();
var threadId2 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
var blogPost = DoSomething2().Result;
var threadId3 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

If You output thread id's, threadId2 and threadId3 in the result will always be the same, so no thread change happens, and the thread is blocked.

```
{
  "threadId1": 30,
  "threadId2": 15,
  "threadId3": 15
}
```

Comment: I agree that FirstOrDefault blocks the thread for example 5 seconds, so I need to use await FirstOrDefaultAsync then thread isn't blocking. In both cases (DoSomething1 and DoSomething2) I call the same async method GetById and use await FirstOrDefaultAsync(). So thread isn't blocking these 5 seconds in both cases? Is it true?

Comment: It works in that way, when You use await - after calling database by DoSomething1, it releases the thread(threadId1 in example), and it can be assigned by thread pool to run other piece of code at the time You await database result. And when the result of database call is returned, the thread pool assigns other thread(threadId2) to proceed. In the case of DoSomething2 thread(threadId2) starts the call to database and waits for the result(at this moment it can't be re-used by thread pool, so it's "locked"), after receiving result - same thread(threadId2) continues to run the code.

Comment: Excellent, I think your example with Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId is the best answer to my question. I tried it in the code. Now I see the difference

Answer (score 2):

It's `DoSomething1()` that will avoid blocking, not `DoSomething2()`.

You use the `async` modifier to specify that a method, lambda expression, or anonymous method is `asynchronous`

An async method runs synchronously until it reaches its first `await` expression, at which point the method is suspended until the awaited task is complete, in this case, that would be the `GetById` async method.

---

You also have an error waiting to happen in your code...

```
public async Task DoSomething1()
{
    var blog = await _blogRepository.GetById(1);
    Console.WriteLine(blog.Title); // this line has the bug
}
```

The `GetById` method internally uses `FirstOrDefault` when searching the underlying database, so if you search for a blog that doesn't exist, the method will return a null object... you're then attempting to access that objects Title property, but because its null... you'll get a null reference exception. Check whether the object is null before attempting to access its properties

Comment: I think that thread blocking happens when FirstOrDefaultAsync is running, so this is reason why I use async GetById method and then await FirstOrDefaulAsync, so is it really need to use one more async in higher methods?

Comment: FirstOrDefaultAsync is `async`, it doesn't block, however your `DoSomething2()` method will block, its no longer async so it will run synchronously

Comment: Okey, FirstOrDefault takes for example 5 seconds and this time thread is blocked. So we use FirstOrDefaultAsync and now thread isn't blocking these 5 seconds. Perfect, so why we must use async await in higher methods like in DoSomething1()?  P. S. this is console or mvc application, not wpf/uwp.

Comment: Lets imagine characters named `Bob`,`Harry`, `Jane`. Imagine `Bob` asks `Harry` to `Fit new tyres` on his car, and that `Bob` *waits* while `Harry` finds tyres for him. Now also imagine that `Harry` is also waiting for `Jane` to send them. so `Bob` is waiting for `Harry` whos waiting on `Jane`. This is `synchronous`. but what if `Jane` told `Harry` that she will let him know when they arrive so he doesn't waste time. and that `Harry` tells `Bob` that he can do something else until the job is done. thats basically what `async` `await` is.If `Jane` is async but `Harry` isn't, `Bob` wont benefit

Comment: Thanks for a very clear explanation, but I think that there are no Bob in this situation (with DoSomething2). There are only two characters Harry which is DoSomething2 caller and then GetById(x).Result caller. And Jane is FirstOrDefaultAsync caller. Are you agree with me?

Comment: Bob is the thread that is making the call to those other methods, if you had a console app it would be the sta thread, if it was a wpf app it would be the UI thread, if it was asp.net... IIS thread...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180992/discussion-between-ka-marius-and-aydin-adn).

Answer (score 1):

Task.Result call will block the calling thread until the operation is completed.

Here is an excellent article explains it well
https://montemagno.com/c-sharp-developers-stop-calling-dot-result/

Comment: This is interesting post. But this not ansver my question. Ok, I understand that is it bad idea to call FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result without async await. For example if this DB call takes 5 second, then thread will block for 5 seconds. So this is reason why we use async await FirstOrDefaultAsync(). Now thread isn&#39;t blocking for these 5 seconds. So question is why we need use async await in higher methods like DoSomethink1()? How do you think?

Comment: I see that both DoSomething1() and DoSomething2() blocking the main thread until the operation is completed.                                                                                                 I suggest to rewrite the DoSomething1() as                                              public async Task DoSomething1()
{
    return _blogRepository.GetById(1);   
}

Comment: Yes, but then I can't access blog.Title for Console.WriteLine(blog.Title). So I thing that thread is not blocked during the db call, because this call is async await and after this call we can use in higher methods Result for accessing data. Are you agree with me?

Comment: When the await keyword is applied, it suspends the calling method and yields control back to its caller until the awaited task is complete.  if  you want to use the result of the operation in higher level methods, you need to use await. Here is an excellent article on how to use await - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a controversial topic and I think it deserves controversial answer so here it goes:

**First of all**, let me make it clear that `DoSomething2` is a blocking method; meaning it will run on calling thread and block the calling thread, while `DoSomething1` will not block the calling thread and will run on thread pool thread instead.

Now, from my understanding of async methods, their sole purpose is to allow parallelism and hence maximum usage of your CPU. What that means from the desktop developer perspective is, you could have a responsive UI when you call async method and you could update UI while work is being offloaded to non-main thread.

If your application is designed to run units of work in parallel then it makes sense, to me, to use `DoSomething1` instead of `DoSomething2` as you could get maximum usage out of your CPU, but if your application is designed to run units of work in sequential manner (as I believe you are doing in your console application) you wouldn't be getting any benefit from using `DoSomething1` as there will be only one operation running at a time and I would use `DoSomething2` instead.

With that being said, you can use `AsyncContext.Run(() => MyMethodAsync(args));` in your console app to run your async method on separate context.

To summarize, unless your console app is doing some parallel work on threads, I would say you will be fine using `DoSomething2`.

P.S you should fix the bug mentioned by @AydinAdn.

Answer (score 0):

if await is applied to the result of a method call that returns a Task Result, then the type of the await expression is Result. If await is applied to the result of a method call that returns a Task, then the type of the await expression is void